# Join and Group multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2016

Lets say I have this relationship on my MSSQL 2016 (later Azure SQL)

```
[ForumBoards] 1-n [ForumThreads] 1-n [ForumPosts] n-1 [Users]
```

We have: 50 Boards, 200k Threads, 1 Million Posts and 50k Users

The target now is

- All boards with ID and Name
- Number of threads inside a board
- Number of posts inside a board
- Latest Post inside a board
- User ID and Name of the latest post

My first show was

```
SELECT 
    Boards.Id AS BoardsId,
    Board.Name AS BoardsName,
    LP.*
        ThreadsCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM ForumBoards AS SubB 
                        JOIN ForumThreads AS SubT ON SubB.Id = SubT.BoardId 
                        WHERE SubB.Id = Boards.Id AND SubT.BoardId = SubB.Id),  
        PostsCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM ForumBoards AS SubB 
                        JOIN ForumThreads AS SubT ON SubB.Id = SubT.BoardId 
                        JOIN ForumPosts AS SubP ON SubT.Id = SubP.ThreadId 
                      WHERE SubB.Id = Boards.Id AND SubT.BoardId = SubB.Id AND SubP.ThreadId = SubT.Id)
FROM ForumBoards as Boards 

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
    TOP 1   SubP.Id AS LatestPostId,
        SubP.PostedOn AS LatestPostPostedOn,
        SubP.ThreadId AS LatestPostThreadId,
        SubT.Topic AS LatestPostThreadTopic,
        SubU.Id AS LatestPostUserId,
        SubU.Username AS LatestPostUsername 
        FROM ForumBoards AS SubB 
             JOIN ForumThreads AS SubT ON SubB.Id = SubT.BoardId 
             JOIN ForumPosts AS SubP ON SubT.Id = SubP.ThreadId 
             JOIN Users AS SubU ON SubP.UserId = SubU.Id 
        WHERE SubB.Id = Boards.Id AND SubT.BoardId = SubB.Id AND SubP.ThreadId = SubT.Id AND SubU.Id = SubP.UserId 
        ORDER BY SubP.PostedOn DESC) AS LP
```

which has an incredible bad performance.

Without

```
WHERE SubB.Id = Boards.Id AND SubT.BoardId = SubB.Id AND SubP.ThreadId = SubT.Id AND SubU.Id = SubP.UserId
```

it costs 45ms, with about 6 seconds.

Another show was this one

```
SELECT  
    B.Id,
    B.Name as BoardName,
    Count(*) as ThreadsCount,
    (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM
        ForumBoards Boards, ForumThreads Threads, ForumPosts Posts
        WHERE Boards.Id = Threads.BoardId AND Threads.Id = Posts.ThreadId AND Boards.Id = B.Id) AS PostsCount

FROM    ForumBoards B, ForumThreads T

WHERE B.Id = T.BoardId

GROUP   BY B.Id, B.Name
```

Which was ok, about 172ms - but without the latest post.

But I think I'm on the wrong side of the hedge. And hints how I can reach my goal?

Comment: have you already created non-clustered indexes on columns that are used in join operations (it's also related to correlated queries)?

Comment: @AliaksandrBortnik MSSQL query ex plan recommended to create `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ForumThreads_BoardRelation ON [dbo].[ForumThreads] ([BoardId]) INCLUDE ([Id])` which was done, yes.

Comment: Are there clustered indexes on IDs in your tables?

Comment: @AliaksandrBortnik yes on all PK

Comment: which SQL server are you using?

Comment: @rigerta oh sorry, local is MSSQL 2016 but later should run on Azure SQL. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this seem to be a forum-look-alike project, so first thing to keep in mind: you'll have way more reading than writing on your DB.

Avoid complex query that should be run every time someone display your front page, it's not a good idea, you'll just end with a sluggy DB.

This kind of problematic is where trigger can by miraculous.

On **`board`** add 5 new columns :

- `nb_threads`
- `nb_posts`
- `last_post_id`
- `last_user_id`
- `last_user_name`

And add the following trigger :

- `ForumThreads.trgAddThread` => +1 to the parent `ForumBoards.nb_threads`
- `ForumThreads.trgDeleteThread` => -1 to the parent `ForumBoards.nb_threads`
- `ForumPosts.trgAddPost` => +1 to the parent `ForumBoards.nb_posts`, set the current post.id to last_post_id, user.id to last_user_id and fetch the user.name to set last_user_name
- `ForumPosts.trgDeletePost` => -1 to the parent `ForumBoards.nb_posts` and go fetch the last post to update the previous data

---

If you can't use trigger (as you explain in comment), this query should do the trick under 400ms :

```
SELECT 
    Boards.Id AS BoardsId,
    Boards.Name AS BoardsName,
    coalesce(nbThread.ThreadsCount, 0) ThreadsCount, 
    coalesce(LP.nbPost, 0) nbPost,
    LP.*,
FROM ForumBoards AS Boards
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT BoardId, Count(*) ThreadsCount
    FROM ForumThreads
    GROUP BY ForumThreads.BoardId
) AS nbThread
    ON nbThread.BoardId = Boards.Id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT   
        t.BoardId,
        t.nbPost,
        ForumPosts.Id AS LatestPostId,
        ForumPosts.PostedOn AS LatestPostPostedOn,
        ForumPosts.ThreadId AS LatestPostThreadId,
        ForumThreads.Topic AS LatestPostThreadTopic,
        Users.Id AS LatestPostUserId,
        Users.Username AS LatestPostUsername 
        FROM (
            select 
                ForumThreads.BoardId, 
                MAX(ForumPosts.Id) Id, 
                Count(*) nbPost
            from ForumPosts
            JOIN ForumThreads
                ON ForumThreads.Id = ForumPosts.ThreadId
            GROUP BY ForumThreads.BoardId
        ) AS t 
        INNER JOIN ForumPosts  
            ON t.Id = ForumPosts.Id 
        INNER JOIN ForumThreads
            ON ForumThreads.Id = ForumPosts.ThreadId
        INNER JOIN Users
            ON Users.Id = ForumPosts.UserId        
) AS LP
    ON LP.BoardId = Boards.Id
```

Comment: Adding the last post related data in the Board itself is actually the best idea! Upvoted! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but we want triggers only if there is no performant solution available. At least there are dozent of triggers needed like thread movements from Board A to B, hidden posts etc etc...

Comment: we do not want to put our BL into the database

Comment: @Ben `no performant solution available` => making a query that browse 1M lines for every view is what I call a "not performant solution", trigger will be **way more** performing. and you don't have to make dozen of trigger, 6 of them will be enough to handle every case that can happen

Comment: @Ben I'm dealing with DB up to some Billion lines, business logic in the DB is something you had to do if you want to keep performance to a decent level as your volume increase. (BTW, this is not real BL, it's what we call "calculated field", it's just here to make once when needed the request you want to do for every view)

Comment: @Blag but we have business logic where anonymous users get other "latest posts" than team users, which can see as example hidden or scheduled posts too.

Comment: @Ben yes, I understand, but this kind of query will really kill the DB for what is nearly "useless" information, it's the same thing with all forums. I don't see the BL in your SQL query, but I assume you'll have to add it here too, no ? The best way for me is to add fields that can keep everything you need, even if it's in another `stats` table with a line for every board & profile

Comment: we use application caching instead of redundant data to avoid db scale issues